# solr. Exact and Partial match

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr. I need to execute a query on a field. Sometimes this query is an exact match, other times it's a partial match.

Is it possible to do this on a single field? Or do I have to create two copy fields: one for the exact match and one for the partial match?

In my collection i have:

```
**desc**
market
mark
m1 market
m1
```

For exact match (desc:mark) I would:

> mark

For partial match (desc:mark) I would:

> market, mark, m1 market

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create two copies of fields.
Just use boolean queries.

**Exact + Partial:**

(desc:mark) OR (desc:mark*)

**Exact:** 
(desc:mark)

**Partial:**

(desc:mark*)

**Fuzzy:**
(desc:mark~1)

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to create a copy field for searching
For partial search use wildcard char * 
* denotes 0 or more chars

query for **partial search** would be like

> desc:* mark*

query for **exact search** for mark will be

> **desc:mark**